# Android Not Playing Custom Notifcation Sound

Tags: android, notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have Notification Channels set up with custom sounds using the SetSound() method. The sounds are stored as resources in the raw folder. For the most part these notifications work and the custom sound is played correctly.

We allow users to change the notification sound from within our app. To handle this we delete the existing channel and create a new one with the new sound - this means that notification channels may be created, deleted and recreated. (I'm not sure if this related or not.)

However, some of our customers have gotten the app into a state where the notifications no longer plays a sound and the only way to resolve the issue is to uninstall and reinstall the app.

In the device's Settings > App > Notifications all the settings are correct and under Sound 'App Provided Sound' is selected. When debugging a device that is having this issue, I've confirmed that the Notification Channel settings are pointing at the correct resource file. I've also called 'OpenRawResource(resourceId)' in the Notification handler to confirm that the app can open the resource file, but FCM isn't playing the sound file.

Is there any way to resolve this? Or any recommendations on how to debug this further?

Comment: Why wont you just use 2 channels? One with sound and one without. Does that solve the problem? Also is there a pattern in which devices is hit with the bug? Manufacturer or Android version?

Comment: We need multiple channels because, depending on the type of notification we use different audio, and for each notification type the user can select different audio.

I think it's only been reported on Samsung devices, but that's not to say that it's only happening on Samsungs.

Comment: And you've testet the issue appears even if you use multiple channels?